# Changing css w/ javascript

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a link, that when clicked, i want its css values to change.  I can do that with this jquery code:

```
    $(".linkname").click(function(){
  $(this).css({'border-style' : 'solid', 'border-width' : '1px', 'border-color' : '#ec6163', 'color' : '#ec6163'});
  return false;
});
```

However, I also want the link's css values to revert to normal when I click the link with the altered css values a second time.  I tried an if else sentence, but it always evaluated else and didn't work.  How can i do this?

Comment: Please post up your version with the if statement.

Comment: Welcome to the community; as this is your first question, I'm going to point you to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Also, it's worth mentioning now that you should select the checkmark next to the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Even better, put all of that CSS into a class and use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch.

```
/* CSS */
.someclass { border: 1px solid #ec6163; color: #ec6163; }

/* JS */
$(".linkname").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('someclass');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think it depends on the situation, or rather the amount of use within the site. Toggling an input button on a contact page (one JS function). Toggling links, divs, etc. site-wide toggleClass/commented CSS - IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using toggle()?

```
$('.linkname').toggle( function() {
        $(this).css({'border-style' : 'solid', 'border-width' : '1px', 'border-color' : '#ec6163', 'color' : '#ec6163'});
    }, function() {
        $(this).css({'border-style' : 'dotted', 'border-width' : '0px', 'border-color' : '#999999', 'color' : '#cc6163'});
});
```

Comment: wow.

thanks a ton.

you just saved me a couple of hours.  tytytyty

Comment: No problem. Had a similar issue myself recently.

Comment: You can use `this.style.borderColor = ` instead of having to call `$` to use the `css()` function

Comment: @Yi - You're right, but I was just trying to show the toggle function. With the amount of styles he's changing, I'd still call the css() function. (Answer edited to show all CSS changes in one line)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your if/else statement didn't work.
Perhaps try using a variable outside of the method to save which state the link is in.

eg.

```
var link_state = 1;

$(".linkname").click(function(){
  if (link_state == 1) {
    $(this).css({'border-style' : 'solid', 'border-width' : '1px', 'border-color' : '#ec6163', 'color' : '#ec6163'});
    link_state = 0;
  }
  else {
    $(this).css({'border-style' : 'none', 'border-width' : '0px', 'border-color' : '#ffffff', 'color' : '#ffffff'});
    link_state = 1;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You forgot the variable's underscore in the IF.

Comment: @D_N : It appear to be there for me, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Hm, right you are. My mobile browser, Opera Mini, won't display it, for whatever dumb, quirky reason. Sorry for the false alarm.